# How to get file from Assets folder in my Windows Store App Project?

Tags: c#, json, windows-runtime

I'm trying to create a phonebook app in windows store apps in which I have to store contacts in a json file. I want to create and access that Json file from my Assets folder in the project.

> I have tried following (none of these are working) :

[Create, Write, and Read a file - Microsoft](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files)

[Jerry Nixon's Blog about Reading and Writing from Files](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html)

**and many others...**

I have tried the following code:

```
StorageFile SFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Data.txt"));

        var display = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(SFile.Path);
        await display.ShowAsync();
```

**Its Reading the following File:**
[image]

**I want it to read the following one:**
[image]

If someone can suggest me the way to do this. Thanks !

Comment: It looks like the path is wrong : "ms-appx:///Assets/Data.txt"

Comment: I don't see any difference in both paths. @jdweng

Comment: What's wrong in that path? @jdweng

Comment: What error are you getting?  Is the issue you can't find the file or the contents of the file?  If contents, what is inside the text file?

Comment: Its not even approaching to the file in the Assets.. @jdweng

Comment: At this point I just want to check if my code is getting the file from custom directory @jdweng

Comment: But it is getting the right file. Your application is getting deployed to bin/debug/appx and the Assets folder with that file is there, is that not right?

Comment: I guess if what you need is to write to that file, then you can't - files in your app package directory are read-only. You'll need to make a copy in `ApplicationData.LocalFolder` on first run if you want to have any data initialized from that packaged file.

Answer (score 0):

Try add **`.txt`** file type as supported file type in `Package.appxmanifest` file of your application ,open file and go to ***Declaration Tab*** then in ***Available Declaration*** dropbox choose this item > **File Type Associations** after that click ***Add*** then in ***Supported File Types*** section fill the content type and file type and click on Add New button , after that when operation complete , save changes.

also you can add it manually by right click on `Package.appxmanifest` file click on View Code then write below piece of code in *Application* tag :

```
<Extensions>
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
      <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="txt">
        <uap:DisplayName>.txt</uap:DisplayName>
        <uap:EditFlags AlwaysUnsafe="true" />
        <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          <uap:FileType ContentType="txt/json">.txt</uap:FileType>
        </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
      </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
    </uap:Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

Comment: Its giving an error "Namespace prefix 'uap' is not defined" . !

Comment: Still reading from the file in the bin > debug > appx > Assets

Comment: @ZaryabWaseem what is your project type ? is it Universal ?

Comment: Its Windows 8 based

Comment: I have added file Support... Its working but still going the wrong path I mentioned above...

Comment: @ZaryabWaseem so maybe you can`t use this solution , it work on UWP projects.

Comment: Oh ... anyway, Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @ZaryabWaseem Are you sure checked **Copy to Output Directory** in properties of json file ?